# How would I do the following replacement using PHP preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string with one to two white spaces. I want to replace the single white spaces with nothing and the double white spaces with a single white space. If simply try to match on ' 'it will nuke all the white spaces. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/ (?! )/', '', $subject);
```

This matches and removes a space only if it's not followed by another space.

Input:  `12 34  56 78  90`  --> Output: `1234 5678 90`

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$string);
```

now all double space will be singled

UPDATE:

```
$replacements = array(' ','');
 preg_replace('/(\s{2})|(\s{1})/',$replacements,$string);
```

This way double space become single, and single become nospace;

Comment: Not what deltanovember wants. He wants to replace single spaces with the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $s = 'SINGLE SPACE-DOUBLE  SPACE';
    echo $s . PHP_EOL;
    $s = strtr(
        $s,
        array(
            '  ' => ' ',
            ' ' => ''
        )
    );
    echo $s . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

PS: I am testing other cases.

Comment: The question is - what would the OP expect in case of 4 spaces? This will return 2 spaces, and Tim's answer will return 3 spaces. Of course, that's undefined behavior `:)`

Comment: @Kobi: I am considering another option: replace all double (or more) white space with a temp character, remove any outstanding white space, replace all temp characters with a space.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace isn't necessary.

```
str_replace('  ', ' ', $string);
```

or, if you want to make sure there are never to spaces in a row, loop it:

```
while (strpos($string, '  ') !== false)
    $string = str_replace('  ', ' ', $string);
```

Unless you mean any whitespace (space, tab, newlines), then you could use:

```
str_replace(array('  ', "\t\t", "\r\r", "\n\n"), array(' ', "\t", "\r", "\n"), $string);
```

Comment: I realize this isn't exactly what OP asked for, but I think the while loop will achieve the same goal.

Comment: It still doesn't remove single spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Single whitespace: `" [^ ]"` (a whitespace which is **not** followed by another).
Double whitespace: `"  "`.

Comment: This fails on spaces at the end of the string (and it will remove the character following the space).

Answer (score 0):

Match on '  ' (two white spaces).  Though for something like this, I think regex is over kill.  Just use the `str_replace()` function and replace all '  ' with ' '.